# Windows 10 - Can't access network share from nowhere

Tags: networking, windows-10

I created a shared folder a while ago which worked perfectly fine but stopped working for whatever reason.

[image]

If I try to access it then a window saying "can't access FreigabeAR":

[image]

I already deactivated my firewall and tried it again, same result.
The shared folder is on the same machine.

Network discovery is on and File- and Printershare is also on.

I can ping my own computer (lol)

Other computers in the network can't access the ressource as well. All computers are in the same workgroup.

I pressed on the diagnose button and it says `The device or resource (BLACK) is not set up to accept connections to the File and Printer Sharing (SMB) port.`

All of the following services are running:

```
1.     DHCP Client
2.     DNS Client
3.     Network Connections
4.     Network Location Awareness
5.     Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
6.     Server
7.     TCP/IP Netbios helper
8.     Workstation
9.     Function Discovery Resource Publication,
10.  UPnP Device Host services
```

**UPDATE:**

I ran the diagnose on another client and found out that the remote computer where the network share lays does block port 445. But even after shutting down the firewall on the remote computer it does still not work.

**UPDATE**

Result of `nbtstat -c`

VMW1:
Node-IP-Adress: [192.168.174.1] Area identifier: []

```
No names in Cache
```

**Note**: VMW1 is my "VM Ware Adapter 1"

Result of `ipconfig /all`:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host name. , , , , , , , , , , , : Black
   Primary DNS suffix. , , , , , , :
   Node type. , , , , , , , , , , , : Hybrid
   IP routing enabled. , , , , , : No
   WINS proxy enabled. , , , , , : No

Ethernet adapter VMW1:

   Connection-specific DNS suffix:
   Description. , , , , , , , , , , : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapters for VMnet1 # 2
   Physical address. , , , , , , , : 00-50-56-C0-00-01
   DHCP enabled. , , , , , , , , , : No
   Autoconfiguration enabled. , , : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 address. : fe80 :: c5c7: 18ad: 1f2e: 3a76% 5 (preferred)
   IPv4 address. , , , , , , , , , : 192.168.174.1 (preferred)
   Subnet mask. , , , , , , , , , : 255.255.255.0
   Standard gateway. , , , , , , , , :
   DHCPv6 IAID. , , , , , , , , , , : 234901590
   DHCPv6 client DUID. , , , , , , , : 00-01-00-01-21-D9-11-23-00-40-F4-EC-55-CB
   DNS server. , , , , , , , , , , : fec0: 0: 0: ffff :: 1% 1
                                       fec0: 0: 0: ffff :: 2% 1
                                       fec0: 0: 0: ffff :: 3% 1
   NetBIOS over TCP / IP. , , , , , , : Activated

Ethernet Adapter TAP:

   Connection-specific DNS suffix:
   Description. , , , , , , , , , , : TAP-Windows Adapter V9
   Physical address. , , , , , , , : 00-FF-49-34-3D-81
   DHCP enabled. , , , , , , , , , : No
   Autoconfiguration enabled. , , : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 address. : fe80 :: f593: e49a: b82d: e4d7% 10 (preferred)
   IPv4 address. , , , , , , , , , : 169.254.123.176 (preferred)
   Subnet mask. , , , , , , , , , : 255.255.0.0
   Standard gateway. , , , , , , , , :
   DHCPv6 IAID. , , , , , , , , , , : 50397001
   DHCPv6 client DUID. , , , , , , , : 00-01-00-01-21-D9-11-23-00-40-F4-EC-55-CB
   DNS server. , , , , , , , , , , : fec0: 0: 0: ffff :: 1% 1
                                       fec0: 0: 0: ffff :: 2% 1
                                       fec0: 0: 0: ffff :: 3% 1
   NetBIOS over TCP / IP. , , , , , , : Disabled

Ethernet adapter Internal card:

   Connection-specific DNS suffix:
   Description. , , , , , , , , , , : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical address. , , , , , , , : BC-5F-F4-63-26-1A
   DHCP enabled. , , , , , , , , , : No
   Autoconfiguration enabled. , , : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 address. : fe80 :: e951: 5de5: 50ec: 8b9b% 14 (Preferred)
   IPv4 address. , , , , , , , , , : 192.168.178.78 (preferred)
   Subnet mask. , , , , , , , , , : 255.255.255.0
   Standard gateway. , , , , , , , , : 192.168.178.1
   DHCPv6 IAID. , , , , , , , , , , : 113008628
   DHCPv6 client DUID. , , , , , , , : 00-01-00-01-21-D9-11-23-00-40-F4-EC-55-CB
   DNS server. , , , , , , , , , , : 192.168.178.1
                                       8.8.8.8
   NetBIOS over TCP / IP. , , , , , , : Disabled
```

Comment: From a Command Prompt please run `netstat -ano | findstr ":445"` and [edit] the output into your question (then ping me @Twisty).

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator, The output is empty.

Comment: Try resetting networking: Search "reset network" in Start. This will delete all network-related settings, e.g. static IP addressing, saved wireless networks, etc. so be sure to document them first.

Comment: I did "reset network", my computer restarted and I had to reenter the IP of the network device and add default gateway, subnet, dns etc. But it failed, I was not even able to ping the default gateway. So I used the internal network card and tried it again, the network worked. However, after restarting my computer, I was getting bluescreens and was unable to start the OS !! I had to start windows in secure mode and run `sfc /scannow` and `chkdsk /f` to repair my computer. Now there are no bluescreens anymore. End of the story: I still can't access the network share, it was not helpful.

Comment: Please 1) run `netstat -c` and post the result, and 2) `ipconfig /all` and post the status of the *NetBIOS over Tcpip* line for your physical network adapter(s).

Comment: Correction for command #1, it is `nbtstat -c`

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator, I updated my question with the infos, hope that helps. I used google translate to translate the output.

Answer (score 1):

Open Run, type “***inetcpl.cpl***” and end with Enter to open Internet Properties/Internet Options. Select Connections tab – LAN settings - uncheck Use a proxy server for your LAN - check Automatically detect settings – click OK to save the change.

Please using command line “**netstat -ano**” to check post **445** and **139** status which are used for file and printer sharing.

If there is anti-virus/protection software, disable it temporarily and check the result. If possible, try **Clean Boot** and confirm that if share folder can be successfully accessed.

Comment: I ran the diagnose on another client and found out that the remote computer where the network share lays does block port 445. But even after shutting down the firewall on the remote computer it does still not work.

Answer (score 1):

Your computer had too many problems, which are seemingly not fully fixed.
Blue screens and inability to boot are serious problems.

I would suggest a more drastic approach : As the computer can still boot,
you can
[Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html),
to "upgrade" Windows to itself.

Read carefully this article, and especially how to download a Windows ISO
of the same major Windows version as the one which is currently installed.
The opening box mentions Refresh and Reset, but these are not the operations
to do - continue on in the article.

This "upgrade" is not destructive and will preserve your data, user accounts,
and installed apps and drivers.
However, as always before doing major operations on Windows,
ensure you have good backups, just in case something goes wrong.

Comment: I never had these bluescreens though, they only started to appear after resetting the network as @Twisty Impersonator recommended. I also had some bluescreens before which appeared after opening firefox while nvidia stereo 3d was activated. I think these bluescreens are because of bad driver and software programming and are not because of hardware failures. I will try it out as soons as I have time, thank you.

Comment: But to be honest, this is not a real solution. I need to find the cause, because I try to understand why exactly this happens.

Comment: There can be many causes, even a Windows update that went wrong. You mentioned some system manipulation that you did, after which the problems started. I don't know exactly what was done to your computer, and you don't know either what did sfc /scannow and chkdsk. In such a case, Repair Install might be able to reset all the components of Windows to one coherent state. Repair Install might fail, but it almost never causes a problem (but better ensure you have backups, including a backup image of the system disk).

Comment: the only manipulation I did on my system was resetting the network as TwistyImpersonator recommended. Why does the remote computer block port 445 and why do I get the same error message saying that the remote computer is blocking port 445 if I deactivate the firewall? I am so confused.

Comment: There might be three firewalls involved 1. The server computer, 2. The router that passes the network request, 3. The client computer might block an outgoing request. Security software installed on server or client might also be involved. I haven't found "reset network" in my Start menu, so I don't know what it does - resetting the network is done [this way](https://www.howtogeek.com/265870/how-to-reset-your-entire-network-in-windows-10-and-start-from-scratch/).

Comment: Resetting your networking should not result in Bluescreens. The fact that it has suggests an unidentified root cause that was brought to light by the reset process.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator: My money would be on something gone wrong, maybe because of a bad Windows update, then the problem was compounded by running sfc /scannow and chkdsk /f. I can see here only the solution of Repair Install for being sure that Windows is consistent again, before going any further with the problem. It would be wrong to leave the computer in its current state with such a history of such problems.

Comment: I will accept your answer, because I think this is a bug and it is the only possible solution. Thank you all!

Comment: *ops, I just noticed that Twisty Impersonator added a comment, I will wait maybe he has another solution. But I can't undo the bounty

Comment: @Black: There is no guarantee that Repair Install will fix the problem, but it will assure that your Windows is in a stable state. If the problem persists, update the post and let me know here, so I can help. Check first all firewalls and antivirus products that might exist on the network between the client and server, and also share permissions and user accounts, and include this information in your post.